# Reading a collection of strings from the user

Tags: c++

I was trying to write a program that will read a collection of strings from the user, and then end the moment it encounters a `"."`. So then I write a `do`-`while` loop.

I came across a something like this:

```
string temp;
vector<string> params;
do
{
    cin >> temp;
    if (temp == ".")
        break;

    params.push_back(temp);

} while (temp != ".");
```

I realized that no matter what, the loop will always end from within its body -- which is the *exact* result that *want*.

But there something about piece of code that smells fishy. Are there any better ways?

Another thing to note: I don't want the `"."` to be pushed onto the vector, hence that's why I added that little `if (temp == ".") break;` statement.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Don't forget to check the stream status for errors or EOF.

```
while (cin >> temp && temp != ".")
{
    params.push_back(temp);
}
```

---

EDIT: You do not necessarily need to invent your own break condition. There's one already — end of file. You can just read strings until you reach it. This way, your program will also work with non-interactive input nicely. To generate an end of file on a terminal, type Ctrl+D on Unix/Linux and Ctrl+Z on Windows.

```
while (cin >> temp)
{
    params.push_back(temp);
}
```

Comment: Almost an extremely nice solution – it just lacks the {} which I strongly prefer to see even for one-line bodies.

Comment: @Christopher: This is a matter of personal style. I will nevertheless edit this answer for better clarity.

Comment: Yes it is, and I didn't mean it any other way. (But note that some versions of gcc will flag such “missing braces” with `-Wall`, which really should be among the standard settings for any developer.)

Comment: Almost an extremely nice solution -- it just has those ugly, completely unnecessary {} polluting and obfuscating otherwise nice code. :-)

Comment: @Christopher Which versions of GCC flag this? I always use `-Wall` (and more), never put the braces and have never seen this warning.

Comment: @Konrad: I am sorry, but I'm rather fuzzy in my memory there. I believe it involved cases with nested `if` statements some of which had an `else` clause. I did not mean to imply I had seen gcc flag all uses of `if` with an unadorned statement.

Answer (score 20):

I prefer:

```
cin >> temp;
while (temp != ".")
{
   params.push_back(temp);
   cin >> temp;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

```
string temp;
vector<string> params;
while (true)
{
    cin >> temp;
    if (temp == ".")
        break;

    params.push_back(temp);

}
```

That test - `true` in my case, `temp != "."` in yours, never really gets run, except when it's true.  So it might as well be `true`.

Comment: This would be my suggestion, with the modification of using for(;;) rather than do {} while(true);  I prefer it to Michael K's answer because it doesn't repeat the "body" of the loop (cin>>temp) and is no slower (while still needs to execute a branch).  If the "body" of the loop was more than one line, it would more clearly be code duplication.

Comment: I would suggest that `while(true)` (without `do`) would be clearer for intentions, even for less experienced programmers, than `for(;;)` or `do while(true)`.

Comment: Good call, @Hosam Aly; I have updated with your suggestion.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I prefer to build some infrastructure that will make the rest of the code trivial. The infrastructure may be a little extra work, but the long-term savings can be substantial. In this case, it takes the form of a special iterator that allows you to specify the "sentinel" that will end the input. It acts like a normal `istream_iterator`, except that you specify the sentinel value when you construct the "end of range" iterator.

```
// sentinel_iterator.h
#pragma once
#if !defined(SENTINEL_ITERATOR_H_)
#define  SENTINEL_ITERATOR_H_
#include <istream>
#include <iterator>

template <class T,
          class charT=char,
          class traits=std::char_traits<charT>,
          class distance = ptrdiff_t>

class sentinel_iterator :
    public std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag,distance,void,void,void>
{
    std::basic_istream<charT,traits> *is;
    T value;
public:
    typedef charT char_type;
    typedef traits traits_type;
    typedef std::basic_istream<charT,traits> istream_type;

    sentinel_iterator(istream_type& s)
        : is(&s)
    { s >> value; }

    sentinel_iterator(T const &s) : is(0), value(s) { }

    const T &operator*() const { return value;  }
    const T *operator->() const { return &value; }

    sentinel_iterator &operator++() {
        (*is)>>value;
        return *this;
    }

    sentinel_iterator &operator++(int) {
        sentinel_iterator tmp = *this;
        (*is)>>value;
        return (tmp);
    }

    bool operator==(sentinel_iterator<T,charT,traits,distance> const &x) {
        return value == x.value;
    }

    bool operator!=(sentinel_iterator<T,charT,traits,distance> const &x) {
        return !(value == x.value);
    }
};

#endif
```

With that in place, reading the data becomes trivial:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include "sentinel_iterator.h"

int main() { 
    // As per spec, read until a "." is entered:
    std::vector<std::string> strings(
        sentinel_iterator<std::string>(std::cin), 
        sentinel_iterator<std::string>("."));

    // It's not restricted to strings either. Read numbers until -1 is entered:
    std::vector<int> numbers(
        sentinel_iterator<int>(std::cin),
        sentinel_iterator<int>(-1));

    // show the strings:
    std::copy(strings.begin(), strings.end(),
        std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));

    // show the numbers:
    std::copy(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(),
        std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));
    return 0;
}
```

Given an input of:

```
This is a string .
1 2 3 5 -1
```

It produces an output of:

```
This
is
a
string
1
2
3
5
```

It should work for essentially any type that defines a stream extractor and testing for equality (i.e., saying `x==y` will compile and produce meaningful results).

Comment: I like the idea (and +1). In contrast, `std::istream_iterator` is comparing stream pointers instead of read values. This has a small efficiency cost because both the constructor and `operator++` need an extra `if()` to see if the read has failed in order to null out the stream pointer. Your `sentinel_iterator` doesn't need that. Could you also use it to read from `std::cin` until a read fails?

Answer (score 3):

If we are not talking about language-specific details then I would prefer something like this:

```
// this is inspired by LINQ and C#
var params = Enumerable.Generate<string>(() => {string temp; cin >> temp; return temp; })
                       .TakeWhile(s => s != ".")
                       .ToVector();
```

Where Enumerable.Generate() is some lambda which reads data from `cin`. Generally answering the question 'how to use breaks?' I think breaks should not be used, at least not in such trivial scenarios.

Comment: I am not a fan of this particular syntax, but I like the methodology.